# Conditional Expectation of function of two RVs, one measurable, one independent

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-sub-algebra in the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let $X$ be a $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function and $Z$ independent on $\mathcal{A}$. Why can I write $$E(f(X,Z) \mid \mathcal{A})=\int_{\Omega} f(X,Z(\omega)) P(d\omega) \text{?}$$
(Note that $X$ <strike>does not depend on</strike> is not a function of $\omega$. The background was that I want to have $E(f(X,Z) \mid \mathcal{A})=E(f(X,Z))$)

**EDIT** Like @Did said, the question should be formulated a bit differently:
**Why is $$E(f(X,Z) \mid \mathcal{A}) = g(X)$$ with $g(x)=E(f(x,Z))$?**

(The integral in the original expression would be more $U(\omega)=\int f(X(\omega),z)\,\mathrm dP_Z(z)$ and I asked myself why $X$ in the integrand is not integrated as well, which I expressed as "is not a function of")

Comment: The plot thickens: $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is an $\mathcal A$-measurable function while $X$ would not be a random variable? Recall that *random variable* is a synonym of *$\mathcal F$-measurable function* and that, if $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal F$, then every $\mathcal A$-measurable function is $\mathcal F$-measurable.

Comment: @Didier No worries, then maybe I should withdraw it, and the other expression is the right way to express what I mean, this came up from a discussion with Gortaur and I think you already gave the answer that's making me understand, I still have to look into the details.

Comment: You will do as you want, I simply do not know what your question is, yet.

Comment: @Didier: I think I had to see that $U(\omega)=∫f(X(\omega),z)dP_Z (z).$ because I thought that after putting $g(X)$ meant $∫f(X(\omega),Z(\omega)) dP (\omega)$ to understand $E(f(X,Z)\mid \mathcal{A}) = g(X)$ (<- so this would be my question) and your answer helped me, I somehow wasn't aware that distributions could help (which is now so obvious)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As often with conditional expectations, to come back to the definition yields the solution. To check that $U=\mathrm E(f(X,Z)\mid \mathcal A)$ is to check that two conditions hold simultaneously: (1) $U$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable; (2) for every bounded and $\mathcal A$-measurable $Y$, one has $\mathrm E(UY)=\mathrm E(f(X,Z)Y)$.

Let us check (1) and (2) for $U=g(X)$ where $g$ is defined by $g(x)=\mathrm E(f(x,Z))$.

Since $U=g(X)$ is a measurable function of $X$ and $X$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable, $U$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable.

Now, $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathcal A$-measurable and $Z$ is independent on $\mathcal A$ hence $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent. Calling $\mu$ the distribution of $(X,Y)$ and $\nu$ the distribution of $Z$, one gets
$$
\mathrm E(f(X,Z)Y)=\iint f(x,z)\,y\,\mathrm d\mu(x,y)\,\mathrm d\nu(z).
$$
On the other hand,
$$
g(x)=\int f(x,z)\,\mathrm d\nu(z),
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm E(UY)=\mathrm E(g(X)Y)=\int g(x)\,y\,\mathrm d\mu(x,y)=\iint f(x,z)\,y\,\mathrm d\nu(z)\,\mathrm d\mu(x,y),
$$
hence $\mathrm E(UY)=\mathrm E(f(X,Z)Y)$ by Fubini theorem. Finally, (1) and (2) hold for $U=g(X)$ hence
$$
\mathrm E(f(X,Z)\mid \mathcal A)=g(X)=\int f(X,z)\,\mathrm dP_Z(z).
$$
This means that $\mathrm E(f(X,Z)\mid \mathcal A)=U$ almost surely, where, for every $\omega$ in $\Omega$,
$$
U(\omega)=\int f(X(\omega),z)\,\mathrm dP_Z(z).
$$
**Note:** All this, and much more, is explained in a gem of a small book, highly accessible, titled [Probability with martingales](http://books.google.com/books?id=e9saZ0YSi-AC&dq=david+williams&printsec=frontcover&source=in&hl=en&ei=PLH4Sb2WCdqwtgf-oPDBDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=14#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: In your question, the mention that *$X$ does not depend on $\omega$* is quite strange. You might want to explain what you mean. Likewise, note that I did not reproduce your displayed formula, because I find it prone to misinterpretations.

Comment: I had $X$ in mind as a function and wanted to say that $X$ is not actually a function of$ \omega$, and yes, that's unfortunate expression in this context. Thanks for your answer

Comment: In which part of the book you mentioned can I find the proof? I searched for it and wasn't able to find it.