# Conditional expectation of a function of two random variables, one measurable, without independence

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$, $Y$ random variables on $ (Ω, \mathcal A, \mathbb P) $, $ \mathcal F ⊂ \mathcal A $ a sub-σ-algebra and $X$ measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal F$. Let $X$ take values in $(E, \mathcal E)$ and $Y$ values in $(E', \mathcal E')$, and consider a measurable map $ g: E \times E' → \mathbb R$ either nonnegative, or bounded, or such that $ g(X,Y) ∈ \mathcal L_1(\mathbb P)$.

I wonder whether it holds that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb E[g(X,Y) | \mathcal F] = \mathbb E[g(x,Y) | \mathcal F] \mid_{x = X} \tag{$*$}.
\end{equation}
If $Y$ happens to be independent from $\mathcal F$, this is indeed the case, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73353/conditional-expectation-of-function-of-two-rvs-one-measurable-one-independent). What can we say without independence?  Does it hold or is there a counterexample? If it does not hold in general, does it hold under some additional assumptions on $X$ and $Y$?

---

**Edit**: Here is a proof attempt using the 'standard machinery' (and where I think it meets an obstacle):

We will use the [functional monotone class theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Monotone_class_theorem_for_functions).
Let $ H $ the set of bounded measurable maps for which $(*)$ holds, which is a vector space containing the constants. For $A ∈ \mathcal E$, $ B ∈ \mathcal E'$ and $ g = I_{A \times B}$, it does indeed hold that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[g(X,Y) | \mathcal F] &= \mathbb E[I_A(X) I_B(Y) | \mathcal F] \\ 
&=I_A(X) \ E[I_B(Y) | \mathcal F] \\
&= \mathbb E[I_A(x) I_B(Y) | \mathcal F] \mid_{x =X} 
= \mathbb E[g(x,Y) | \mathcal F] \mid_{x =X},
\end{align*}
so $H$ contains indicators of sets in $ \mathcal E \times \mathcal E'$, which is a $π$-system generating $\mathcal E \otimes \mathcal  E'$. If we can show that $H$ is in addition closed under nonnegative monotone convergence, it follows that $H$ contains all bounded $\mathcal E \otimes \mathcal  E'$ measurable functions and we are (mostly) done. So let $0 \leq g ∈ H$ and $(g_n) ⊂ H$ with $0 \leq g_n ↗ g$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[g(X,Y) | \mathcal F] &\overset{a.s.}{=} \lim_{n → ∞} \mathbb E[g_n(X,Y) | \mathcal F] \\
&= \lim_{n → ∞} \mathbb E[g_n(x,Y) | \mathcal F]\mid_{x = X} \\
&\overset{(?)}{=}
\lim_{n → ∞} \mathbb E[g(x,Y) | \mathcal F]\mid_{x = X}.
\end{align*}
I see the following issue with the last equality. Let $ G_n(ω,x) := \mathbb E[g_n(x,Y)| \mathcal F](ω)$, then from $g_n ↗ g$, $G_n(ω,x) → G(ω,x) =: E[g(x,Y)| \mathcal F](ω) $ almost surely, i.e. for all $ω ∈ N_x^c$ where $\mathbb P [N_x ] = 0$. But the exceptional set $N_x$ of those $ω$ where convergence fails to hold depends on $x$, so unless, say $E$ is countable, these sets may accumulate to prevent convergence on a set with positive measure.

Comment: The theorem which holds for $Y$ independent of ${\cal F}$ says something different: \begin{equation}
\mathbb E[g(X,Y) | \mathcal F] = \mathbb E[g(x,Y)] \mid_{x = X} .
\end{equation} That is: there is an ordinary expectation on the RHS, not a conditional one. This becomes false when $Y$ is not independent of ${\cal F}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, I added a proof attempt. I think the standard arguments are not quite sufficient here.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem which holds for $X$ being ${\cal F}$-measurable and $Y$
independent of $\cal F$
says something different:
$$\tag{1}
\mathbb E\big[g(X,Y)\big|\mathcal F\big]=\mathbb E\big[g(x,Y)\big]\mid_{x=X}.
$$
That is: there is an ordinary expectation on the RHS, not a conditional one.

This is false when $Y$ is not independent of $\cal F\,:$

***Counterexample***

Let $Y=X$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are not independent and, for ${\cal F}=\sigma(X)\,,$  $Y$ is not independent of ${\cal F}\,.$ Then for $g(X,Y)=XY$ we have
$$
\mathbb E\big[g(X,Y)\big|{\cal F}\big]=XY=X^2\,.
$$
On the other hand, when $X$, and therefore $Y$, has expectation zero the RHS of (1) becomes
$$
X\,\mathbb E[Y]=0\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I agree that in the case in which $Y$ is independent from $\mathcal F$, eq. (1) holds. But in my understanding, this is equivalent to $\mathbb E[g(X,Y) | \mathcal F] = \mathbb E[g(x,Y) | \mathcal F] \mid_{x = X} $, since with independence, the conditional expectation becomes an unconditional one.

For the original formulation without independence, the counterexample does not work, since $\mathbb E[g(x,Y) | \mathcal F] \mid_{x = X}  = xY \mid_{x  =X } = XY = \mathbb E[XY|\mathcal F]$.

Comment: The version you have in OP I have never seen. Let's try the following. Assume $X,Y$ are both ${\cal F}$-measurable (not necessarily $Y$ independent). By the tower property $\mathbb E[g(X,Y)|{\cal F}]=E[g(X,Y)|\sigma(X,Y)]\,.$ Then by the Doob-Dynkin lemma this is a deterministic function $f$ of $X,Y\,.$ This $f(x,y)$ is often written as $\mathbb E[g(X,Y)|X=x,Y=y]\,.$ I believe this is a more standard way of expressing your version.

Comment: Actually, it is simpler. When $Y$ is as in my last comment then $\mathbb E[g(X,Y)|{\cal F}]=g(X,Y)\,.$ The case that needs to be studied is therefore $Y$ neither ${\cal F}$-measurable, nor independent thereof. This is usually approached by showing it first for functions $g(x,y)$ of the form $f(x)h(y)$ for which your formula is trivial. To show it for all functions a monotone class theorem can be used I think. @geetha290krm's comment is of a similar spirit.

Comment: I have edited the OP with a proof attempt. It seems to me there is an argument missing though.

Comment: Thanks. Before I try to unravel this just one more remark: the proof of my classic version (1) should be the same as your version and along the lines I mentioned in the previous comment. I cannot give you a reference but maybe you want to look for one in the internet.

Comment: Agreed! I think the proof in the op (which is very similar to your idea) works when $Y$ is independent of $\mathcal F$ and then shows your eq. (1), since in this case (the conditional expectations being unconditional) the obstruction from exceptional sets piling to cause trouble does not happen.